# java - update client GUIs

Tags: java, user-interface, sockets

I am trying to make a Texas Holdem LAN game. Game flow is finished and I am now starting server/client-communication using sockets. My question is this:

What is the best way to update changes to the table (player folds etc.) in the clients GUI's? Is there a favored consept in this situation?

I have a JPanel with the table, communitycards, players etc. - Is it possible (or a good idea) to regularly send this JPanel to the clients?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why send the whole jPanel? that is too much going over the socket.

Just send enough information for each clients GUI to repaint the table themselves.

Comment: Especially when dealing with a network, but as a general rule, you should only be sending the required information to update the ui.

Comment: On the same note, why would the server have anything to do with JPanels? It should data structures that it sends back and forth. What if you want to add support for another platform eventually. Let's say, Android, since it's also Java. Would the server also hold details on the Android's UI?

Comment: Thanks. I figured that would be the alternative.

Comment: another question: what is the best way to invoke methods over the socket?

Answer (score 0):

You want to make use of [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

In your client code where it is communicating with the server and receiving data based on which you want to update your UI elements, do something like -

```
public void clientSideOfClientServerCommunication(final someClass someData){
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
      //use someData to update GUI elements.
    }
  });
}
```